# What does `tar -C` mean?

Tags: linux, tar, gentoo

In the section "Installing Portage", the [Gentoo installation docs](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=1&chap=5#doc_chap3) say:

```
# tar xvjf /mnt/gentoo/portage-latest.tar.bz2 -C /mnt/gentoo/usr
```

What does this command do?

Answer (score 32):

Tar is used to handle archives (historically saved on tapes).

- The `x` tells it to extract files from the archive
- `v` stands for verbose
- `j` for bzip2 archive
- `f` indicates the file name
- finally: `C` tells it to change directory (so the package content will be unpacked there)

See also `man tar`.

Comment: I've also seen -C used while creating an archive. What does it mean in that context?

Comment: @frakman1: Do I really have to copy the contents of `man tar` here?

Comment: The man page just says `change to directory DIR` which is not very helpful. Saying "(so the package content will be unpacked there)" on the other hand, is.

Comment: OK. When -C is used while creating an archive, it specifies where to search for the files to archive.

Answer (score 12):

If you ever need to know what a parameter does again, try to read the man first. The command `man tar`, and then doing `/-C` will get you to the section describing what -C stands for, which in this example represents 'change directory' (i.e. sends the results of the unpacking to `/mnt/gentoo/usr`).

Answer (score 4):

It unpacks `/mnt/gentoo/portage-latest.tar.bz2` in `/mnt/gentoo/usr/`